# How do I dynamically center images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

With css and javascript/jquery, how do I center the images I have displayed vertically down a page? Let me draw a diagram. 
This is what I have...

```
-------
|     |
|     |
-------
----------
|        |
|        |
----------
------
|    |
|    |
------
```

This is what I want

```
  -------
  |     |
  |     |
  -------
-----------
|         |
|         |
-----------
   -----
   |   |
   |   |
   -----
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the following CSS on your centered image class:

```
display: block;
margin: 1em auto; /* the key here is auto on the left and right */
```

Comment: if the image is taking up 100% of it's container ( because it's a block ) then this won't do anything right? Because auto will try to center a 100% width object.

Comment: @Brad, Look at the screen OP provided, he does not want Images to take 100% width.

Comment: i can't seem to get this to work. does it matter of the container is not 100% of the window width?

Comment: Just tried this in jsfiddle. Cool stuff Brad. Didn't know that this worked.
http://jsfiddle.net/r9BfT/2/

Comment: @Wilfred, Can you post your code in JSFiddle or somewhere?  Do you have any floats?

Answer (score 3):

If you place each image within a `<div class="img">` then set the style of those to;

```
div.img{ 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

*adjust the width to match your needs.

Alternative, you can set the width of the `<div class="img">` to 100% and centre the text;

```
div.img{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small snippet will get this done

```
display: inline-block;
margin: 1em auto;
```

Using jQuery you can set the properties like:

```
$("img#selector").css({
    'display':'inline-block',
    'margin' : '1em auto'
});
```